# Sharedpreference Edittext in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

So far, I have a fragment, wherein there are 2x edittexts and a button. What i need to do, is to save texts I have written in edittext, so that when I change to another fragment and then back, then i'll see the last thing i wrote in the Edittexts.

To solve this, I am using sharedpreference, but I can only make it work with a button, so that the text inside edittext is saved when I press the button, and then I retrieve it on onCreate in fragment. What i would like is to update automatic, so I don't have to press any button.

```
public class KontaktFragment extends Fragment {

private EditText beskedTekst;
private EditText emneTekst;
private Button kontaktSend;

public KontaktFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_kontakt, container, false );

    beskedTekst = (EditText) view.findViewById( R.id.beskedEdit );
    emneTekst = (EditText) view.findViewById( R.id.emneEdit );
    kontaktSend = (Button) view.findViewById( R.id.kontaktButton );

    hentTekst();

    kontaktSend.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMail();
        }
    } );
    return view;
}

public void sendMail() {

    String besked = beskedTekst.getText().toString();
    String emne = emneTekst.getText().toString();

    //String recipientList = kontaktTekst.getText().toString();
    //String[] recipients = recipientList.split(",");

    gemTekst();

    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"xxx"} );
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emne );
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, besked );

    intent.setType( "message/rfc822" );

    startActivity( Intent.createChooser( intent, "Vælg en email klient" ) );

    intent.setData( Uri.parse( "mailto:" ) );
}

public void gemTekst() {

    String besked = beskedTekst.getText().toString();
    String emne = emneTekst.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences( "kontakt", 0 );
    SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
    sedt.putString( "textvalue", besked );
    sedt.putString( "txtopertaive", emne );
    sedt.commit();

}

public void hentTekst() {

    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences( "kontakt", 0 );
    String tValue = sp.getString( "textvalue", "" );
    String tOperative = sp.getString( "txtopertaive", "" );

    beskedTekst.setText( tValue );
    emneTekst.setText( tOperative );   

   }

}
```

Comment: Add this method `gemTekst();` in `onPause()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onPause` lifecycle method in fragments & add your required methods.

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    gemTekst();
}
```

Comment: Welcome glad to help..! Happy coding :)